# Check if value is neq to 2 or 4

Tags: typescript

In short: What is the reason this is not working?

```
let i: number = 2;

if (i != 2 || i != 4) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

ERROR: Operator != cannot be applied to types 2 and 4.
But they are "type" number, are they not? Btw. this is working with == Operator, but it ain't working with a mix of != and == operators.

You can reproduce it here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/
With the code from above. Also, this Error comes up in a current Angular6 project. It is a little bit annoying, because I have to rewrite the if-else with ==.

I might add, the error doesnt show up when I manually add < number> in front of the variables, or when I declare i as being of Type Number. However, adding < number> or declare i as Number will result in unexpected behaviour (it's still not working as expected). Is this a bug or what is the sane reason behind this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler has caught an error in your logic. Your condition will always be true, and I guess that you meant to use `&&` instead of `||`.

If `i != 2` is false then `i == 2`, in which case the type of `i` is narrowed to a single number, `2` (you typed it as `number` above). This is the only case in which the second half of your condition will be evaluated. The error is that a variable of type `2` cannot be compared against one of type `4`.

Comment: awwwwwww this makes sense. Wow. Thank you, I didnt quite see that...  Stupid